# How to map over a list with <NULL> conditionally?

Tags: r, purrr

I want to use `map()` to apply `summary()` on the result of `lm()`. As long as I run the `lm()` on all nested groups ("VC" and "OJ"), it works. But how do I do that if `lm()` was not applicable for one group (e.g., "VC")? I tried with `map_if()` and `map_at()` to get lin.mod.res in that case but failed. Any idea?

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'dplyr'
#> Die folgenden Objekte sind maskiert von 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> Die folgenden Objekte sind maskiert von 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

as_tibble(ToothGrowth) %>%
  group_by(supp) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    lin.mod = map(data, ~ (lm(len ~ dose, .))),
    lin.mod.res = map(lin.mod, ~ summary(.))
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   supp [2]
#>   supp  data              lin.mod lin.mod.res
#>   <fct> <list>            <list>  <list>     
#> 1 VC    <tibble [30 x 2]> <lm>    <smmry.lm> 
#> 2 OJ    <tibble [30 x 2]> <lm>    <smmry.lm>

as_tibble(ToothGrowth) %>%
  group_by(supp) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    lin.mod = map_if(data, supp != "VC", ~ (lm(len ~ dose, .)), .else = "NA")
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Groups:   supp [2]
#>   supp  data              lin.mod
#>   <fct> <list>            <list> 
#> 1 VC    <tibble [30 x 2]> <NULL> 
#> 2 OJ    <tibble [30 x 2]> <lm>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It can be a function

```
as_tibble(ToothGrowth) %>%
  group_by(supp) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    lin.mod = map_if(data, supp != "VC", ~ (lm(len ~ dose, .)), .else = ~ NA)
  )
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   supp [2]
  supp  data              lin.mod  
  <fct> <list>            <list>   
1 VC    <tibble [30 × 2]> <lgl [1]>
2 OJ    <tibble [30 × 2]> <lm>
```